# Gaussian Mixture description

Tags: normal-distribution, gaussian-mixture-distribution, multivariate-normal-distribution, finite-mixture-model

Looking at this link on Gaussian Mixtures and EM:
[http://www.ics.uci.edu/~smyth/courses/cs274/notes/EMnotes.pdf](http://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Esmyth/courses/cs274/notes/EMnotes.pdf)

from the link:

Given a data set D = {$x_1, x_N$} where $x_i$ is a d-dimesional vector. Assume that the points are generated from a density p(x). Further assume p(x) is a finite mixture model with K components:

p(x|$\theta$) = $\sum_1^K \alpha_kp_k(x|z_k,\theta_k)$

where $\alpha_k$ are the mixture weights. $\sum_{k=1}^K\alpha_k=1$

the author then says on page 2 under Gaussian Mixture Models"
We can define a gaussian mixture model by making each of the k components a gaussian density with parameters $\mu_k$ and $\sum_k$. **Each component is a multivariate gaussian density.**

My question is: Is the last statement correct? Is each component multivariate gaussian?

Here is an example:

I have a 1-dimensional vector, X, with 2 components:

```
X
.67
.9
2.2
5.1
....
```

I was thinking for gaussian mixtures each observation in the X vector is either from component 1 or 2. So the first entry .67 would be either from

**set up #1**

k=1 ~ N($\mu_1,\sigma_1$) or

k=2 ~ N($\mu_2,\sigma_2$)

However, the author is saying .67 is either from 2 multivariate distributions:

**set up #1**

k=1 ~ N($\mu_1^1, \mu_2^1; \sum_1$) or

k=2 ~ N($\mu_1^2, \mu_2^2; \sum_2$)

So given the example above what is the correct setup #1 or #2?

Just thinking about this in the context of the EM algorithm to estimate the parameters of the model I think it is #1 because at each iteration of the EM algorithm you are estimating the parameters of a **single** multivariate distribution.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to confuse sample and observations: if one takes $n$ observations from a $p$-dimensional mixture distribution, each observation is a $p$-dimensional vector. It is associated with a latent variable that takes as value 1,2,... depending on which component the vector is generated from.

To make the distinction even clearer, here is a sample of 250 points generated from a univariate mixture$$0.3\mathcal{N}(0,1)+0.7\mathcal{N}(2,1)$$

[image]

generated as

```
data=(rnorm(250)+(runif(250)<.7)*2)
```

and here s a sample of 250 points generated from a bivariate mixture$$0.3\mathcal{N}_2(0_2,I_2)+0.7\mathcal{N}_2((6,-3),i)$$

[image]

generated as

```
dota=rmvnorm(250,mean=rep(0,2))+(runif(250)<.7)*c(6,-3)
```

In the first case, the sample starts with

```
> data[1:10]
 [1]  1.1093865  3.9148698  0.7089910  0.8179517  2.1479357  1.1273827
 [7]  1.9081127  1.5963952  3.0439887 -0.7480628
```

and in the second case it begins as

```
> dota[1:10,]
           [,1]       [,2]
 [1,]  4.082637 -2.3638552
 [2,]  6.417835 -1.9432360
 [3,]  5.619073 -0.8438118
 [4,]  6.704312 -3.1426273
 [5,]  6.000480 -2.8611720
 [6,]  5.370948 -2.0932625
 [7,] -1.202043  0.7533113
 [8,] -0.384621 -0.4188970
 [9,]  6.910961 -1.3184499
[10,]  4.453260 -2.9979343
```

Comment: Yes the .67 will have a latent variable,z, that is 1 or 2 indicating if .67 came from distribution 1 or 2. My question is are the distributions,1 &2, multivariate or univarite....setup #1 or #2

Comment: If 0.67 is _one_ observation this is a one-dimension mixture (setup #1). If 0.67 is a component of an observation vector, for instance, (0.67,2.2), this is a two-dimensional mixture (setup #2).

Comment: what if the observation vector has 100 term  (.67, 2.2,1.5.......) then you would say there are a 100 dimensional mixture with k=1 ~ N(mu1,mu2, ...mu100, covariace matrix 100x100)? In my example I state this is 1 dimensional vector, X, with 2 components. Components are distributions.

Comment: It doesn't matter how many observations X has, 1 or 2 or 100, each observation will only come from 1 of 2 distributions, k=1 or k=2.  the distributions do not change from being univariate to multivariate based on the length of X. my question is given 1 vector, i.e. 1 D, and 2 components are the components univariate or multivariate. The author says multivariate and with k=2,  that would mean in the EM algorithm you'd have to estimate 4 means and 2 covariance matricies each time through the loop. I believe you only estimate 2 means and 1 covariance matrix in the loop.

Comment: The meaning of X itself is unclear. Let me repeat my answer: the dimension of the mixture is the dimension of each observation in the sample.

Comment: X is 1 dimensional vector

Comment: in the link you see "The membership weights above reflect our uncertainty, given xi and , about which of the K components
generated vector xi. Note that we are assuming in our generative mixture model that each xi was
generated by a single component—so these probabilities reflect our uncertainty about which component xi
came from, not any “mixing” in the generative process." That is saying .67 came from only 1 component like N(0,1) not a weighted mixture in your plot.

Comment: So when the author says "Each component is a multivariate gaussian density." that is only true if X has dimension >1. If X is 1 dimension like my example,  then each of the components are univariate distributions.Do you agree?

Comment: Yes, if the author states this, each $X_i$ in your sample is multivariate.

Comment: "each Xi  in your sample is multivariate.".  I think you mean each component is multivariate if d>1 otherwise if d = 1 then each component is univariate